# CentOS 6 - Manually Compile libmcrypt

Tags: centos

I need to compile mcrypt on my server to get the PHP ecommerce software package "Magento" to work correctly. Unfortunately libmcrypt is not available via the default CentOS repo, and I don't feel comfortable following the steps outlined @ [CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge#head-f0c3ecee3dbb407e4eed79a56ec0ae92d1398e01) wiki.

I am quite comfortable compiling libraries manually, but I can't seem to find a trusted source from which to download the libmcrypt source file. I did come across the file @ [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/Libmcrypt/), but when I attempt to compile, it complained that it couldn't find a local install of libmcrypt.

Where can I get the libmcrypt source files, from a trusted source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe mcrypt and libmcrypt is available on EPEL.

To set up the EPEL repo, look at: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

It should be considered relatively trustworthy, in that it's part of the Fedora project.

Here's the link to the libmcrypt RPM (if, for some reason, you want to install the RPM directly without activating the repo): http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/repoview/libmcrypt.html

The URL will be similar to the mcrypt package.